# Kibana Not Showing Logs Sent to Elasticsearch From Node.js Winston Logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am sending logs directly to Elasticsearch from a Node.js app using the `winston` and `winston-elasticsearch` packages. Elasticsearch 7.5.1, Logstash & Kibana 7.5.1 were deployed on a remote server using Docker Compose.

**Problem 1:** After running the node.js file that sends 2 log messages to Elasticsearch, the program does not automatically exit to return to the terminal. Using Node.js v12.6.0 on Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.6.

**Problem 2:** After these 2 log messages were sent to Elasticsearch, they can be viewed using a web browser at `http://<example.com>:9200/logs-2020.02.01/_search`.

```
{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":2,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"logs-2020.02.01","_type":"_doc","_id":"85GgA3ABiaPPk4as1pEc","_score":1.0,"_source":{"@timestamp":"2020-02-02T02:00:35.789Z","message":"a debug message","severity":"debug","fields":{}}},{"_index":"logs-2020.02.01","_type":"_doc","_id":"9JGgA3ABiaPPk4as1pEc","_score":1.0,"_source":{"@timestamp":"2020-02-02T02:00:35.791Z","message":"an info log","severity":"info","fields":{}}}]}}
```

However, these logs do not show up on Kibana, such as the Logs section at `https://<example.com>/app/infra#/logs/stream?_g=()`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to get the logs to also show up on Kibana? Also, why is the Node.js app not exiting after sending the log messages?

Thank you!

**Node.js App**

```
const winston = require('winston');
const ElasticsearchWinston = require('winston-elasticsearch');
const options = {
    console: {
        level: 'debug',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true
    },
    elasticsearch: {
        level: 'debug',
        clientOpts: {
            node: 'http://user:pass@example.com:9200',
            log: 'debug',
            maxRetries: 2,
            requestTimeout: 10000,
            sniffOnStart: false,
        }
    }
}

var logger = winston.createLogger({
    exitOnError: false,
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(options.console),
        new ElasticsearchWinston(options.elasticsearch)
    ]
});

logger.debug('a debug message');
logger.info('an info log');
```

Comment: Not sure if you sorted this or not. But in order for logs to show in the Log Stream you need to use the Bulk API with Create action. and the index of `logs-yy-MM-dd` so `logs-2022-01-07` and the `@timestamp` is required and definitely `message` at least - Log streams is a new concept in ES 7.9 I think. We use the Bulk API for this and our logs show up in this stream. Just for curious - The Stream concept comes from EventSourcing Streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a node.js expert so I will only focus on the kibana issue. The Logs app is not meant to be for "custom" logs/indices like yours.

As stated in the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-logs.html):

> The Logs app in Kibana enables you to explore logs for **common servers, containers, and services.**

The logs app is for monitoring your infrastructure and ELK-Services, e.g. through certain Beats-modules (e.g. the Elasticsearch-, Kibana- and Logstash-Module of Filebeat).

Also from the docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-logs-configuring.html):

> The default source configuration for logs is specified in the Logs app settings in the Kibana configuration file. The default configuration uses the **filebeat-* index pattern** to query the data.

This explains why you dont see any data in the logs app since your indices use the 'logs-*' index pattern.

**Long story short:**

To view the documents in your log-* indices, you need to open the Discovery (first icon on the left sidebar in Kibana) and select the index pattern you already have set up. This is the appropriate way of searching your application data in Kibana.

I hope I could help you.